# What's using my Exchange server to send email via SMTP?

Tags: exchange, smtp, exchange-2016

We have two Exchange Servers (2016 CU9), `EX-OLD` and `EX-NEW`. There are various systems, processes, scheduled tasks and scripts in the business that send emails through our Exchange servers by connecting through SMTP.

We've tracked down a large number of these and updated their configuration to use `EX-NEW` but are quietly confident that there will still be processes lurking that are using `EX-OLD`.

Is there a way to determine what's still using `EX-OLD` for SMTP via Exchange?

Comment: Look at the Exchange transport logs, run a network capture on the server for a few hours and see what inbound SMTP traffic is hitting it, etc., etc.

Comment: What's the configuration of your virtual directories and DNS records?
You can check the IIS log as well.

Comment: @joeqwerty - that sounds like the start of an answer to me! :) Regarding Exchange transport logs, that sounds like the most promising as some of these processes are periodic and may run only once a week - having wireshark or similar running for that long doesn't seem ideal, assuming that the logs will give me sufficient info (message id, source server?) to track things down

Comment: @joyceshen I'm not sure how either of those will help, AFAIK IIS isn't responsible for receiving SMTP email in Exchange and the IP addresses behind EX-OLD and EX-NEW won't have any bearing on the discovery process?